# Standard way of keeping Dockerhub credentials in Kubernetes YAML resource

Tags: kubernetes, dockerhub

I am currently implementing CI/CD pipeline using docker , Kubernetes and Jenkins for my micro services deployment. And I am testing the pipeline using the public repository that I created in Dockerhub.com. When I tried the deployment using Kubernetes Helm chart , I were able to add my all credentials in Value.yaml file -the default file getting for adding the all configuration when we creating a helm chart.

**Confusion**

Now I removed my helm chart , and I am only using deployment and service n plane YAML files. SO How I can add my Dockerhub credentials here ?

1. Do I need to use environment variable ? Or Do I need to create any separate YAML file for credentials and need to give reference in Deployment.yaml file ?
2. If I am using imagePullSecrets way How I can create separate YAML file for credentials ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Kubernetes point of view: [Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) you can create secrets and add necessary information into your yaml (Pod/Deployment)

Steps:

**1**. Create a Secret by providing credentials on the command line:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

**2**. Create a Pod that uses your Secret (example pod):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the dockerhub creds as environment variables at jenkins only and Imagepullsecrets are to be made as per kubernetes doc, as they are one time things, you can directly add them to the required clusters